# RoR tinymce-rails-imageupload get URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a beginner level. And I can not get the image url (i do not know how).
https://github.com/Atlantia/tinymce-rails-imageupload

1.Controller

```
class TinymceAssetsController < ApplicationController  
  def create
    DataFile.save(params[:file])

    render json: {
    image: {
      url: view_context.image_url(image)
    }
 end
}
```

2.Model

```
class DataFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.save(file)
    name = file.original_filename
    #create the file path
    path = File.join(directory, name)
    #write the file
    File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(file.read) }
  end
end
```

File is saved, but I do not know how to get the url ...
thanks for the help.

I decided to do with Paperclip. But there is a problem.

```
class DataFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :file, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
end

class TinymceAssetsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @datafile.update_attributes(file: params[:file])

  render json: {
    image: {
      url: @datafile.file.url(:medium)
    }
  }
  end
end
```

**NoMethodError (undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass)**

and another question:
if I did not point out the style, the picture will have the original size?

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution using dragonfly.. gem 'dragonfly',         '0.9.12'
https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/

1.controller

```
class TinymceAssetsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @image = StaticImage.new(:page_image => params[:file])
    @image.save    
    render json: {
      image: {
        url: @image.page_image.url
      }
    }, content_type: "text/html"
  end
end
```

2. Model

```
class StaticImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  image_accessor :page_image
  attr_accessible :page_image
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of the gem you linked, it doesn't appear to handle the file saving/processing for you, just linking it in TinyMCE.

I'd recommend combining the gem with Paperclip ( https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip )

```
class Datafile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :file, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

Then you can just pass the file object in update_attributes to it:

```
@datafile.update_attributes(:file => params[:file])
```

and call it in the view with

```
@datafile.file.url(:medium)
```

If you want to keep handling it yourself, it's being saved to your file system in directory/ the original file's name from the user ...which probably leaves you open to injection attacks and bad file names! If you do generate it yourself, you could use the Dir class to look through the file system for the correct filename?

EDIT

Okay, given the amend to the question, here's what your controller code should look like:

```
class TinymceAssetsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @datafile = DataFile.create(file: params[:file])


      render json: {
        image: {
          url: @datafile.file.url(:medium)
        }
      }
  end
end
```

In your example, you aren't instantiating the @datafile object, so it's nil. You either need to pull a DataFile out of the database, or instantiate it. Basically, Paperclip abstracts the file handling so it is like a regular attribute. You still need to create the object in the database etc that it's an attribute on!

Comment: Upload pictures to be used very rarely. As for the Dir class, as it is right to implement? Thank you.

Comment: Paperclip handles general file uploads fine...just don't pass it a styles hash, and it will store the file and retrieve it for you.

`Dir.entries("mydirname")` will provide you a list of filenames in a directory, so if you really want to do it yourself, I'd store all the files for a user in a subdirectory ("uploads/#{self.id}/") and then use Dir.entries if you need to find a list of files without touching the database. Again though, I'd really emphasise you using a proper upload management gem!

Comment: Joe, could you help with Paperclip. NoMethodError (undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass). Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like your @datafile object is nil. Are you instantiating it? (DataFile.find(params[:id]) or similar?

Comment: I have not had time to do it. I went back to the project. All is well preserved. But the window does not appear tinymce picture. Thank you

Comment: I can not figure out whether I pass URL. url: view_context.image_url(image).

Answer (score 0):

I did it the following way:

Controller:

```
# For uploading images frm TinyMCE

class TinymceAssetsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # Take upload from params[:file] and store it somehow...
    # Optionally also accept params[:hint] and consume if needed

    image=Image.save(params[:file])
    render json: {
      image: {
        url: view_context.image_url(image)
      }
    }, content_type: "text/html"
  end
end
```

Model for saving the Image

```
class Image

  def self.save(file)
    name = file.original_filename
    #create the file path
    write_path = File.join(Rails.root,'public','images','upload', name)
    return_path = File.join('upload', name)
    #write the file
    File.open(write_path, "wb") { |f| f.write(file.read) }
    return_path
  end

end
```

That saves the file into public/images/upload and inserts correctly the right URL by Tinymce.